# How to get Google Maps image acquisition date?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We're embedding a Google map with javascript and would like to get the image acquisition date. In case i have the terminology incorrect, i would like to get the date the satellite or arial image was captured. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not from their public javascript API.  There is no information about the specific tiles used in the tilesets available.

Comment: Thanks. That's not what i wanted to hear, but good to know for sure.